# Show that [4,5] and [4,12] are equivalent or have the same cardinality

Tags: proof-verification, cardinals, interval-arithmetic

I have 2 intervals, $[4,5]$ and $[4,12]$, so far I've just have found the bijection between the two which is $f: [4,5] \to [4,12]$, $f(x) = 8x-28$.

If you can, make a full example proof step by step.
Edit : 
Thanks to quasi and fleablood for providing a neat proof

Comment: How do you define "equivalent"? If you want a formal proof of something, you first need a formal definition of that thing...

Comment: If you've proved that the function $f$ is, in fact. a bijection, then you've proved that the sets have equal cardinality, so if that's what you mean by equivalence, you're done.

Comment: But how do you prove function f is a bijection?

Comment: Note also that it's enough (by Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein) to find injections between the two sets. This is a bit of overkill here, but it's a useful technique generally. In your particular problem, one injection is trivial: the inclusion $[4,5] \to [4,12]$. An injection the other way is, for instance, $x \mapsto \frac{x+28}{x}$ (which I just got by inverting the function you gave).

Comment: To prove the function $f$ is bijective, there are various ways. One way is to show that it's both injective and surjective, To show $f$ is injective, assume $f(x)=f(y)$, and based on that assumption, prove that $x=y$. To show $f$ is surjective, show that for an arbitrary $b \in [4,12]$, there is some $a \in [4,5]$ such that $f(a)=b$. To find $a$, just solve the equation $f(a)=b$ for $a$ in terms of $b$, and show that the resulting expression for a is in the interval $[4,5]$.

Comment: @quasi : I proved the function f is injective but I don't know how to write a proof for surjective and please correct my errors too.

Comment: @Peter wayne: For surjectivity, try the approach I suggested in a previous comment. Leaving $b$ unknown, and assuming $b \in [4,12]$, solve the equation $f(a) = b$ for $a$. Can you do the algebra for that?

Comment: @quasi : f(a)=b; b=8a-28; a=8b-28; a=(y+28)/8

Comment: You have $b=8a-28$. You don't have $a=8b-28$.

Comment: What I'd do: Prove your function is continuous and strictly growing (its derivative is f'(x) = 8 > 0). Since it is continuous and strictly growing, find its maximum and minimum (which, of course, are 4 and 12). Then, you have that your function spans the full interval (because it is continuous, there must always exist an x in [4,5] such that f(x) = y, for all y in [4,12]

Comment: What would be the right answer?

Comment: You have it right at the end, except $y$ should be $b$. In other words, if you solve the equation $f(a) = b$ for $a$, you should end up with
$$a = \frac{b+28}{8}$$
Now all you have to do is show $a \in [4,5]$. To do that, start with the inrequality 
$$4 \le b \le 12$$
and then prove
$$4 \le \frac{b+28}{8} \le 5$$

Comment: I suggest that  you edit your question to show your attempt, rather than as a comment.

Comment: Is my newly attempted proof correct?

Comment: No.  Showing a single example is never a proof.  Just solve for $8x -28 = y$.  That's is to say, of any $y$, if $x = \frac {y+28}8$ then $f(x) = f(\frac {y+28}8)=8*(\frac {y+28}8) -28 = y$.  As if $4 \le y \le 12$ then $\frac {4 + 28}8 = 4 \le x=\frac {y+28}8 \le \frac {12+28}8 = 5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f\:[4,5] \to [4,12]$ be defined by $f(x) = 8x - 28$.

**Edit:**

In light of fleablood's answer, the statement

$\qquad$Let $f:[4,5] \to [4,12]$ be defined by . . . .

needs some verification.

Specifically, we need to show that for any input $x$ in $[4,5]$, the output $f(x)$ is in $[4,12]$.

Thus, for $x \in [4,5]$, let $f(x) = 8x-28$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&x \in [4,5]\\[4pt]
\implies\;&4 \le x \le 5\\[4pt]
\implies\;&32 \le 8x \le 40\\[4pt]
\implies\;&4 \le 8x-28 \le 12\\[4pt]
\implies\;&4 \le f(x) \le 12\\[4pt]
\implies\;&f(x) \in [4,12]\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Therefore $f$ is a function from $[4,5]$ to $[4,12],\;$i.e., $f:[4,5] \to [4,12]$.

**end Edit**

The goal is to show $f$ is a bijection.

First, we show $f$ is injective.

Suppose $f(x) = f(y)$, for some $x,y \in [4,5]$.

\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&f(x) = f(y)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&8x-28 = 8y-28\\[4pt]
\implies\;&8x = 8y\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x = y\\[8pt]
&
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\text{Therefore $f$ is injective.}
\end{align*}

Next, we show $f$ is surjective.

Let $b \in [4,12]$, and let $a = {\large{\frac{b+28}{8}}}$.

Claim $a \in [4,5]$, and $f(a) = b$.
\begin{align*}
&
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\text{First we show $a \in [4,5]\,$:}\\[4pt]
&b \in [4,12]\\[4pt]
\implies\;&4 \le b \le 12\\[4pt]
\implies\;&32 \le b+28 \le 40\\[4pt]
\implies\;&4 \le \frac{b+28}{8} \le 5\\[4pt]
\implies\;&4 \le a \le 5\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a \in [4,5]\\[4pt]
&\text{as claimed.}\\[12pt]
&
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\text{Next we show $f(a)=b\,$:}\\[4pt]
f(a) &= 8a - 28\\[4pt]
&=8\left(\frac{b+28}{8}\right)-28\\[4pt]
&=(b+28)-28\\[4pt]
&=b\\[4pt]
&\text{as claimed.}\\[12pt]
&
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\text{Therefore $f$ is surjective.}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Since $f$ is both injective and surjective, $f$ is bijective.

Remark: We found $a$ by solving the equation $f(a)=b$ for $a$, but that was side work.  The proof doesn't need to show the details of how we found $a$. It only needs to show that the $a$ we chose actually works. Of course, if someone asks "How did you figure out what expression to use for $a$?", you can show the side work.

Comment: Thanks for the perspicuously written answer! Quick question: Does equivalent or same cardinality means same amount of real numbers in the two intervals?

Comment: The phrase "same amount of elements" is informal. The phrase "same cardinality" is one particular formalization of that informal concept.

Comment: Regarding the way to proof a function is injective, then every existing function is then injective? it would just goes like this f(x)=f(y); ... ; x=y

Comment: No, not true. If $x=y$, then $f(x)=f(y)$. But $f(x)=f(y)$ does not automatically imply $x=y$. For example, suppose $f(x) = x^2$. Then 
$f(-3) = f(3)$, but $-3 \ne 3$, which shows that $f$ is _not_ injective.

Comment: f(x)=x^2 ; f(x) = f(y) ; x^2 = y^2 ; √x = √y ; x = y

Comment: No, not true. What is true is that $x^2=y^2$ yields $x = \pm y$. It doesn't yield $x=y$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT. 1) Draw an angle between $0^{\circ}$ and $90^{\circ}$.

2) enter the intervals $[a,b]$ and $[A,B]$ in such a way that their ends touch the sides of the angle.

3) a line that passes through the vertex of the angle in its interior cuts $[a,b]$ in $x$ and $[A,B]$ in $f(x)$.

4) The geometric intuition tells you that $f$ is a bijection and the analytic form of this function depends on the position you give to the figures in the coordinate plane.

Answer (score 0):

To prove $f(x) = 8x -28$ is a bijection you need to prove three very easy things.

1) $f: [4,5]\to [4,12]$.  Or in other words: $x \in [4,5]\implies f(x) \in [4,12]$

2) $f$ is injective.  Or in other words  $f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$.

3) $f$ is surjective.  Or in other words: if $y \in [4,12]$ then is an $x\in [4,5]$ so that $f(x) = y$.

===

Proof 1)  If $4 \le x \le 5$ then

$32 \le 8x \le 40$ and

$ 4 \le 8x -28 \le 12$ and so $4 \le f(x) \le 12$.

$4= 8*4 - 28 \le 8x -28=f(x) \le 8*5 - 28 = 12$.

So $x \in [4,5] \implies f(x) \in [4,12]$.

2) If $f(x) = f(y)$ then $8x - 28 = 8y - 28$ and therefore $x =y$.

3) For any $y$ so that $4 \le y \le 12$, if $f(x) = 8x-28 = y$ then $x =\frac {y+28}8$.

And if $4 \le y = 8x -28 \le 12$ then

$32 \le 8x \le 12$

$4 \le x \le 5$.

For every $y \in [4,12]$ there is an $x = \frac {y + 28}8 \in [4,5]$ so that $f(x) = y$.